# How to Install English Version of Texmaker/Texstudio?

Tags: latex

I installed Texmaker, and later TexStudio, on my PC. Each time German versions of the programs were installed.  A possible reason may be that I am in Germany.  However, I need English version of one of these programs.  Any help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if a program has a correct internationalization, you should be able to run whichever language version setting the `LANGUAGE` environment variable.

For example, my system default to English (US), but I have installed language support (1) for Italian and Spanish.

So I can for example do (in a terminal)

```
LANGUAGE=it_IT gedit
```

and I have gedit in Italian.  So in principle

```
LANGUAGE=en_US texmaker
```

(if you have support for US English Installed) should start the `texmaker` interface in English... but it does not work.

In `texmaker` there is a menu option for choosing the interface language:

[image: texmaker interface]

To see the list of installed languages ("locales") you can use

```
locale -a
```

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) Control Center -> Language support (at least in gnome).